# UNIX Account management

Tags: linux, security, access-control

Would like to know if there's some opensource solution aimed to manage and administer system authentication and RSA keys for staff, contractors and clients across the organization.

My systems to consider are source control (bitbucket, github), VPN/Firewall, linux, AWS consoles, Jira, CI (jenkins), NAS (synology), phone system, email, etc.

I saw there was Dell One Identity as an enterprise option; but would like to know if there's some open source option I can count with.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability I would run [FreeIPA](https://www.freeipa.org/page/Main_Page). It can do [SSH public key management](https://www.freeipa.org/images/d/d2/Freeipa30_SSH_Public_Keys.pdf) along with a lot of other things like setting up central sudo policies, automount policies, password policies, managing user x509 certificates, and do host-based access control. The latest versions even let you do a one-way trust with Active Directory with the eventual goal being to support two-way trusts.

The only real question is whether all those systems are going to support running some sort of FreeIPA client. On GNU/Linux that client is usually sssd but I'd imagine there's some sort of way of gluing other platforms together since it's essentially just LDAP+Kerberos as far as user authentication is concerned.

**EDIT:**

Not related to your IDM-related question, but if you're trying to scale out central management you might also check out [katello](http://www.katello.org/) for systems management functions.